# Prove that if $ax=b$ has a solution, $R$ is a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, alternative-proof

***Question:***

> Assume that $R$ is a ring which has more than $1$ members, such that
>   for all $a,b\in R$, If $a\neq 0$, The equation $ax=b$ has a solution.
>
> Prove that $R$ is a division ring.

**I saw a huge(!!) proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948675/showing-a-ring-where-ax-b-has-a-solution-for-all-non-zero-a-b-is-a-divisi). I thought that it can be proved easier! But, I'm not sure if my way is correct...**

Let $a$ be a non-zero member of $R$. $ax=a$ has a solution. Call that solution $1_R$.

Now, $ax=1_R$ should have a solution too! So, call that solution $a^{-1}$.

It seems so simple. Am i wrong?

Comment: $ax=a$ may have more than one solution.To illustrate, in $\mathbb{Z}_6, 2.4=2$. So you can't choose $1_R$ uniquely. Which means that $1_R$ may not be the identity of the whole ring.

Comment: At $19$ lines of succinct sentences, that proof is hardly *huge*.

Comment: @rschwieb it uses the concept of endomorphism... I can't use something like that

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade Why not?

Comment: @rschwieb we haven't learned it

Comment: @ArmanMalekzade Everything there translates directly into ring elements, and there is nothing to fear except the terminology. If you'll write it out you'll see how it proves the solution for $ax=a$ is an identity, and it quickly follows that every nonzero element has an inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined $1_R$. But you haven't shown that $1_Ra=a$ nor that
$b1_R=b$ or $1_Rb=b$ for any other element $b$.

Now if you really do have a unit element, you have $a^{-1}$ with
$aa^{-1}=1_R$, but you still need $a^{-1}a=1_R$.